# Does MySQL allows to create database with dot?

Tags: mysql, database, naming-conventions

Does MySQL allows to create database which has dot (`.`) in its name?

I'm using MySQL 5.1.22.

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow (`.`) (`.`)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can't use the dot in a database name. Also, I'd avoid using it in any identifier. A common convention is to use underscore instead. It will serve the same purpose and will avoid a LOT of confusion. If you **do** have a good reason for using strange and otherwise-illegal characters in a table or field name, then you have to escape it.

to escape identifiers in MySQL, use the backtick:

```
SELECT `select`, `some.field name`, `crazy()naming+here`
FROM `my-=+table`
```

Getting into the habit of backticking all field names regardless of whether you *need* to is a good practice in my opinion, but that's another story.

Comment: I disagree strongly about back ticking being good practice.  MySQL specific.  Don't do it unless you have to.  The column names should (imho) be pure ^[a-z0-9_]+$, and not clash with reserved words.  The postgres equivalent is "Weird Column Name" (which preserves case, spaces, allows reserved words etc).

Comment: @user37607, some information why backticking is bad practice would be great!

Comment: @Sam, like he said, it's specific to MySQL, which means that if you need to switch to a different database vendor, you have to update all your SQL. You can change the MySQL escape character so that it is  ANSI-compliant syntax by using the ANSI_QUOTES flag: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand what he meant. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Is it just me that hates seeing the unnecessary backticks? They're ugly. And if you need them, something should be wrong (which is another reason not to use them).

Comment: I strongly disagree with using any database-specific identifier quoting mechanism. There are several problems with them: 1) it makes the code just that much harder to read; 2) all these quoting mechanisms are vendor/product specific (MySQL uses backticks, Oracle uses double-quotes, SQL Server uses square brackets)  so if you want to change database engines all the SQL which uses quoted identifiers must be changed; 3) quoted identifiers are case sensitive, so you not only have to spell your identifers correctly, you have to "CameL_cAsE" them the same way every time. BadIdea (tm)! :-)

Answer (score 29):

You can use `.` in names from MySQL 5.1.6 [according to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html).

However, as has been said and will said again, *please* don't do it.  For every problem you think you're solving now you'll be creating five which will bite you later on.  Since . is used to qualify names - e.g. `database.table` or `table.column` you'll have to quote your database name every time you use it.*

You can do this with backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE `do.not.do.this` (col INT);
```

or using double quotes if you set the following option:

```
SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
CREATE TABLE "asking.for.problems" (col INT);
```

<sub>* Not strictly true - you have to quote any character that's not alphanumeric or `_` or `$` , but . is a particularly troublesome option to have in your names.</sub>

Comment: +1 for 'do.not.do.this' and 'asking.for.problems' ... just beautiful.

Comment: @RichardMorgan Using "." in a table name: "each time you do it, God kills a puppy".

Answer (score 6):

Before MySQL 5.1.6, database and table names cannot contain `/`, `\`, `.`, or characters that are not allowed in file names (see [8.2. Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html)). 
In versions after 5.1.6 you have to quote your tablename with a backtick (`` ` ``) - but as others also advised: you shouldn't do this to prevent any unnecessary trouble.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 5.0.22 doesn't appear to allow it:

```
% mysqladmin -uroot -pXXX create foo.bar
mysqladmin: CREATE DATABASE failed; error: 'Incorrect database name 'foo.bar''
```

Even it if it did allow it, I would strongly recommend against it.

At the very least you'd have to escape any reference to that database with backticks in every single query that ever uses it.

Comment: Yes, don't, even if you can. Same goes for table names with whitespace or unicode or case-sensitivity. You are just asking for trouble that way.