# Dropping a table in MySQL (3.23.58) with a special character in the tablename

Tags: mysql

Yes this is an old db (we are in the process of migrating).  Somehow, phpMyAdmin let a user create a table with a ' in it.

name:  type_save'

But, I cannot seem to drop that table now.  I have tried this from the commandline:

```
mysql> drop table "type_save\'";
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax near '"type_save\'"' at line 1                                                                          

mysql> drop table "type_save'";
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax near '"type_save'"' at line 1    


mysql> drop table `type_save'`;
'>
```

How do you properly escape this?

Thanks...

Comment: Even enclosing the table name in backticks, it still won't delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's MySQL 3.x, so it's very likely MyISAM (or even ISAM). Since the normal way to drop the table isn't working (since you say it crashes the server), and if it's MyISAM/ISAM, just delete the relevant `.MYI`, `.MYD`, and `.frm` files straight from the filesystem, or move them elsewhere if you need to preserve them for some reason. Then do a flush tables. You don't even need to shut down the server (at least on Unix, on Windows the file may be in use and Windows may not let you delete it. Flush tables may help).

Do not do this if its InnoDB, only ISAM or MyISAM.

If its InnoDB, I'm afraid you may have a dump/reload in your future.

And have backups, of course. Always have backups.

Comment: Well, I figured out a work-around by doing a 'mysqldump' of that db, going in and editing the sql file and removing everything to do with that table, saving the sql dump, drop the db, and re-import the sql dump. It also brought down the db when I dropped the db that this table is in, so I had to start mysql again, but at least I got rid of it!

Comment: Oh, and it was a InnoDB table, so I couldn't use that MyISAM trick of removing the filesystem files - I have done that a few times :-)

Comment: @Bruce: That mysqldump you did is what I meant by havingh a 'dump/reload in your future'. Should have been more clear on that, I suppose.

Comment: I thought that is what you meant :-)  Many thanks for everyones help!  stackoverflow rocks!

Answer (score 10):

According to [Does MySQL allows to create database with dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776123/mysql-dot-in-database-name) you use backticks to quote the name, as in

```
drop table `type_save'`
```

Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and it doesn't see, to work.  If we try to use phpMyAdmin, we actually crash the whole db:

Comment: Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort...
thd->query at 0x89d68f0 = DROP  TABLE  `type_save'`
thd->thread_id=45115

Comment: These comments don't show the bactick properly, but they were in the copy/paste to this textarea.

Comment: I hadn't noticed you're using MySQL v3.  Hmmmm...try doubling the single-quote, e.g. drop table type_save''.

Comment: That didn't work either, Bob.  Tried two single-quotes.  There must be some way to do this.  I don't know why it allowed it in the first place...

Comment: Well, I figured out a work-around by doing a 'mysqldump' of that db, going in and editing the sql file and removing everything to do with that table, saving the sql dump, drop the db, and re-import the sql dump.  It also brought down the db when I dropped the db that this table is in, so I had to start mysql again, but at least I got rid of it!

Comment: This worked for me for a table with brackets [] in the file name

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
mysql> drop table `type_save'`;
```

Note: "mysql>" is only the command prompt.

Character is ` (**reverse apostrophe** or left single quote).

Comment: mysql> drop table `type_save'`;
    '>