# Incorrect syntax when . is there in table name

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have MySQL Workbench 6.0 CE installed on my PC.

I have script as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `eh-dbf374d5-f90f-435f-b284-3990e857c46c` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `eh-dbf374d5-f90f-435f-b284-3990e857c46c`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.13, for Win32 (x86)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: eh-dbf374d5-f90f-435f-b284-3990e857c46c
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.15

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `account.info.csp`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account.info.csp`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `account.info.csp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accountInfoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `courseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sectionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `periodID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`accountInfoID`,`courseID`,`sectionID`,`periodID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34013 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `account.info.csp`
--

LOCK TABLES `account.info.csp` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `account.info.csp` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `account.info.csp` VALUES (1,461,3,2,1),(3647,256,49,4,8),(3648,1412,370,6,2),(3649,752,49,12,5),(3650,635,246,12,2),(3651,1878,423,8,1),,(31087,5109,652,3,2),(31088,5109,653,3,3),(31089,5630,654,3,4),(31090,5109,655,3,5),(31091,5109,656,3,8),(31092,5634,658,3,7),(31093,5638,659,3,9),(31094,5648,677,5,3),(31095,5235,679,2,11),(31096,5235,668,2,1),(31097,5235,669,2,2),(31098,5235,670,2,3),(31099,4587,671,2,4),(31100,5235,672,2,5),(31101,5235,673,2,8),(31102,5234,674,2,6),(31103,6640,675,2,7),(31104,5456,679,2,11),(31105,5456,668,2,1),(31106,5456,669,2,2),(31107,5456,670,2,3),(31108,6653,671,2,4),(31109,5456,672,2,5),(31110,5456,673,2,8),(31111,4290,674,2,6),(31112,4625,675,2,7),(31113,4288,676,2,9),(31114,5254,694,2,11),(31115,5254,695,2,1),(31116,5254,696,2,2),(31117,5254,697,2,3),(31118,5254,699,2,5),(31119,5254,700,2,8),(31120,4236,701,2,6),(31121,5253,702,2,7),(31122,5247,703,2,9),(31123,5290,691,4,11),(31124,5290,680,4,1),(31125,5290,681,4,2),(31126,5290,682,4,3),(31127,4252,683,4,4),(31128,5290,684,4,5),(31129,5290,685,4,8),(31130,5299,686,4,6),(31131,5305,687,4,7),(31132,5287,688,4,9),(31133,4909,643,15,11),(31134,4909,680,15,1),(31135,4909,681,15,2),(31136,4909,682,15,3),(31137,4909,683,15,4),(31138,4909,684,15,5),(31139,4909,685,15,8),(31140,4909,686,15,6),(31141,4909,687,15,7),(31142,4909,688,15,9),(31143,6721,679,4,11),(31144,6721,668,4,1),(31145,6721,669,4,2),(31146,6795,671,4,4),(31147,6721,672,4,5),(31148,6721,673,4,8),(31149,4248,674,4,6),(31150,4952,675,4,7),(31151,5279,676,4,9),(31152,4273,679,5,11),(31153,4273,668,5,1),(31154,4273,669,5,2),(31155,4273,670,5,3),(31156,5406,671,5,4),(31157,4273,672,5,5),(31158,4273,673,5,8),(31159,5407,674,5,6),(31160,5408,675,5,7),(31161,5411,676,5,9),(31162,5410,677,4,3),(31163,5523,650,3,11),(31164,5523,651,3,1),(31165,5523,652,3,2),(31166,5546,653,4,3),(31167,5517,654,3,4),(31168,5523,655,3,5),(31169,5523,656,3,8),(31170,5520,657,3,6),(31171,5534,659,3,9),(31172,4649,679,5,11),(31173,4649,668,5,1),(31174,4649,669,5,2),(31175,4315,671,5,4),(31176,4649,672,5,5),(31177,4649,673,5,8),(31178,4786,674,5,6),(31179,6644,675,5,7),(31180,4319,676,5,9),(31181,4251,677,2,3),(31182,5582,679,2,11),(31183,5582,668,2,1),(31184,5582,669,2,2),(31185,4649,670,5,3),(31186,4315,671,2,4),(31187,5582,672,2,5),(31188,5582,673,2,8),(31189,4786,674,2,6),(31190,6644,675,2,7),(31191,4319,676,2,9),(31192,5582,670,2,3),(31193,5084,679,5,11),(31194,5084,668,5,1),(31195,5084,669,5,2),(31196,5084,670,5,3),(31197,6795,671,5,4),(31198,5084,672,5,5),(31199,5084,673,5,8),(31200,4248,674,5,6),(31201,4952,675,5,7),(31202,5279,676,5,9),(31203,6808,679,5,11),(31204,6808,668,5,1),(31205,6808,669,5,2),(31206,6808,670,5,3),(31207,5670,671,5,4),(31208,6808,672,5,5),(31209,6808,673,5,8),(31210,4345,674,5,6),(31211,4348,675,5,7),(31212,4667,676,5,9),(31213,6666,660,2,11),(31214,6666,668,34,1),(31215,6666,669,34,2),(31216,6666,670,34,3),(31217,6666,671,34,4),(31218,6666,672,34,5),(31219,6666,673,34,8),(31220,6666,674,34,6),(31221,6666,675,34,7),(31222,6666,676,34,9),(31223,6667,660,4,11),(31224,6805,670,4,3),(31225,5104,679,5,11),(31226,5104,668,5,1),(31227,5104,669,5,2),(31228,5104,670,5,3),(31229,5556,671,5,4),(31230,5104,672,5,5),(31231,5104,673,5,8),(31232,4313,674,5,6),(31233,5568,675,5,7),(31234,5558,676,5,9),(31235,4241,679,2,11),(31236,5320,691,5,11),(31237,5320,680,5,1),(31238,5320,681,5,2),(31239,5320,682,5,3),(31240,5325,683,5,4),(31241,5320,684,5,5),(31242,5320,685,5,8),(31243,5315,686,5,6),(31244,4257,687,5,7),(31245,4609,688,5,9),(31246,5410,650,4,11),(31247,5410,651,4,1),(33999,4472,327,5,1),(34000,5218,365,3,4),(34001,6617,244,3,4),(34002,5162,2,4,2),(34011,5926,9,10,5),(34012,5969,5,12,7);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `account.info.csp` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2014-05-05 12:01:08
```

When i run above script: it gives me following error.

```
Error Code: 1103. Incorrect table name 'account.info.csp'
```

The error is only when i put dot(.) in between table name.

I have run same script on my co-workers machine, with same MySqlWorkbench 6.0.

It ran successfully and tables got created with dot(.) in between there table names.

Is there any setting i will have to do for this to run??

Or any other alternative????

Edit: Version :

[image]

**EDIT2:**

[image]

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Dot isn't allowed before 5.1.6. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Although using dots in table names is allowed post 5.1.6 (according to doc), it is not recommended, see answers here   :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776123/mysql-dot-in-database-name

Comment: I am using 6.0 version

Comment: @NagarajS is it by any way related with wamp server version??? Its wamp2.0 in my pc

Comment: @AngryTiger 6.0 is version of Workbench, not server. 6.X MySQL server don't exist

Comment: @mleko  how to check server version then?? coz, i have only workbench installed on my pc related to MYSQL

Comment: http://bit.ly/1fJohW9 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-version.html

Comment: @mleko plz see my EDIt2 , what things from above i do need to install???

Comment: Have you checked server versions ?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement has 1 extra comma as showing below after entry (3651,1878,423,8,1),,. just erase it and try.

```
INSERT INTO `account.info.csp` VALUES (1,461,3,2,1),(3647,256,49,4,8),(3648,1412,370,6,2),(3649,752,49,12,5),(3650,635,246,12,2),(3651,1878,423,8,1),,(31087,5109,652,3,2)
```

Comment: I will remove that comma, but error is related to dots(.) in table name.

Comment: as you are saying that this backup was restoring on your colleague machine but not on your machine but this should not restore on any machine due to this error, so there can be gap...further once try after correcting it as some time mysql provide different massage than actual error. If still you are getting table related error then please share the command you are using to restore this backup.

Comment: There were too much data for insert into statement, i cut down that data because of number of characters limitation while posting the question... while cutting the data there was mistakenly "," remained over there...but as i mentioned in the question main error is due to "." in table name...how can i resolve it?

Comment: how you are restoring this backup..as per my assumption you will be doing it by "mysql -uuser -ppassword db < script.sql" ..if it is what is the path of mysql command...there can be a reason that you are using mysql command of any older version even you are using mysql 6.0...