# Laravel DB Config, Adding Periods to Prefix

Tags: php, database, laravel, configuration, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5 config/database.php file I have the following driver defined.

```
'Portal' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_PORTAL', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'prefix'   => 'Portal.dbo.',
        ],
```

When I add a period `.` in the prefix (currently set to `Portal.dbo.`), I get a white screen with no exception or stack trace information. I have enabled DB logging, but the page stops loading before any logging can take place. When I remove the `.` from the prefix, everything appends correctly to the query as it should. 
I need to prefix my queries in such a way because I have more than one databases on the same SQL Server that I want to run Joins between. How can I use periods in my prefix without Laravel crashing?

Comment: I would just use "_" then

Comment: You can't use periods in the database name, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/776135/2696690). Use of underscores instead is strongly recommended.

Comment: The white screen for the fatal error...are you on HHMV?