# Why doesn't my java hibernate application work?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have created my first java hibernate application. Code that I used are as bellow.

**Persistent Class**

```
package com.synapsys;
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String mobile;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

**Mapping File**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.synapsys.Employee" table="tbl.employee">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property name="age" type="int"></property>
        <property name="mobile" type="java.lang.String"></property>
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

**Configuration File**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/employeedb</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Class that stores the Persistent Object**

```
package com.synapsys;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class StoreData {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");     
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();     
        Session session = factory.openSession();        
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setId(1);
        e1.setName("Amal");
        e1.setAge(25);
        e1.setMobile("0717896541");

        session.persist(e1);
        t.commit();
        session.close();

        System.out.println("Successfully saved!");
    }
}
```

When I try to run this application it give following error.

**Eclipse Console**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.synapsys.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:22)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'tbl.employee' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:1154)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1773)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1257)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:959)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'tbl.employee' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1751)
    ... 12 more
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: `Table 'tbl.employee' doesn't exist`. try changing hbm2ddl.auto to "create".

Comment: What part of the error message is difficult to understand?

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion but it doesn't work.@Nicholas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have table-names with dots in them. Underscore should work ok.

[Does MySQL allows to create database with dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776123/does-mysql-allows-to-create-database-with-dot)

(This is an answer and not a comment.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon. It's working. I renamed my table as _tbl_employee_ and the application works fine. Thanks again.