# Are there any good reasons for not using dots in mysql username?

Tags: mysql

Is it bad practice to use dots in a username for Mysql? And more important, why? What can go wrong? For example: john.doe

Comment: what do you mean with "dots in a username"? What username? The users that log into mysql, a username stored inside a field in the db?

Comment: I mean the username with which you login into Mysql, yes. To have a dot in the username example: user.name

Comment: Well , As far as I know dots were never supposed to be valid characters for usernames. The historical reasons are many, including the syntax
of some commands that take username as a parameter. Several commands will that username.group as a parameter and, as you can see, the dot can get in the way of that.

Comment: @Vijay Could you please give an example of a command that takes a username as a param, and how it gets in the way? Thanks!

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776123/does-mysql-allows-to-create-database-with-dot): exact duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MySQL allows to create database with dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776123/does-mysql-allows-to-create-database-with-dot)

Comment: Lelio, that's about naming your db...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good (?) reason would be that it's impractical to have user names with dots, because it's not a valid identifier. That means you have to enclose it in backticks (``` `` ```) in statements like `create user`, `grant`, `set password`, and probably others.

In itself it's not a big issue, and it's certainly allowed to use various special characters, as long as you are aware that you may need those backticks.

Same argument goes for spaces and other special characters in table names and column names, of course. My personal preference would be to not do that, but that's just an opinion. You have to decide that for yourself.

See [MySQL: account names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html)