# How can i create a table that contains "." character?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a table named "localhost.localdomain" and when I run this:

```
        CREATE TABLE localhost.localdomain (User TEXT);
```

or this:

```
        CREATE TABLE "localhost.localdomain" (User TEXT);
```

I get the error "no such table: localhost.localdomain".

I wanted to know is there any way to create a table with such names which contain "."?

Comment: In MySQL the objects names are quoted by backticks (another symbols may be used in special cases only) - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html , so ```CREATE TABLE `localhost.localdomain` (User TEXT);```. In SQLite you may use backticks, double quotes or square brackets - https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: thank you i appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Before MySQL 5.1.6, database and table names cannot contain /, , ., or characters that are not allowed in file names (see [8.2. Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html)). In versions after 5.1.6 you have to quote your table name with a backtick (`) - but as others also advised: you shouldn't do this to prevent any unnecessary trouble.

Check more in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776123/does-mysql-allows-to-create-database-with-dot)...